# Writing a query in Hibernate at repository and at the service

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have 2-query that I need to add at Hibernate.

In the repository, I have done this type of query if can be named like that, but the problem is the using alter is my first time because usually we use only select in the repository.

And the exception I have is this and is only for the first query because I had commented out the second one, but it happens the same:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   
 Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.xitee.ccpt.entity.ProjectEmployee com.xitee.ccpt.repository.ProjectEmployeeRepository.dropConstraint()!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87).
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix or what is wrong with my code?

[service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHMGz.png)
[repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAWz1.png)

Comment: Normally you don't want to drop/add constraints at runtime, one of the reason is that if multiple clients do it at the same time, it will fail. Are you trying to solve a constraint error by removing the constraints temporarily?

Comment: yeah i have a menu and in case the user wants to edit , i have to save it first, cause i have a check on code for time intervals and to save the correct one.And so this constrain does allow that, so i trying in case of edit to disable/deleted and after the save to created it again

Comment: In most use case you want constraints to be valid at all times. Probably there should be some validation in your application before the data is sent to the database.

Comment: in this case is just for a moment and i have limits on code, cause except edit the does not have a a method but works deleted the old one and create the new one, i have to see if there dates are not crashed/the same.

Comment: Can you help me to find a solution about this? @Guillaume

Comment: @Aleksandra, drop me your addConstraint method implenetation.

Comment: @MS90 is at the question, or tell me what else can i get for you to see

Comment: Drop me projectEmployeeRepository.addConstraint(); @Aleksandra

Comment: public static final String ADD_CONSTRAINT = "ALTER TABLE "
                                                    + " ProjectEmployee"
                                                    + "CHECK (check_periods_overlap(employee_id, project_id,start_date, end_date)=CAST "
                                                    + "(0 AS BIT))";

Comment: @Query(ADD_CONSTRAINT)
        public ProjectEmployee addConstraint();

Comment: all this are at the question  i have also add two picture for better understaning....wrtite me at my email if you thing you can help me cause i really need help ..this is my bro email. shkelzentarja@gmail.com

Comment: Trying to drop the constraint will only get you so far, this really looks like a bad idea, you should not be dropping constraints at runtime.

Comment: yeah i am trying to do a diff solution... but seems like impossible ,,, has anyway to put a delay  to constraint , or something

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at the [javadoc of `Query` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#value--). `value` field is a JPA query. This means, you cannot drop constraint with it, you would have to use native query like that:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("your drop goes here");
```

The method should look like:

```
public void dropConstraint() {
    session.createSQLQuery(DROP_CONSTRAINT).executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: yeah i had a look but still i am lost

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand it ... the pieces of code you wrote should i write at the service or repository or at java class i need it

Comment: Instead of using `@Query`, you should put your drop in what I have written and then run it...

Comment: That is wrong... It's too many errors to list in comments. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I try this one but the session , what should i import for it to make it work? Cause does not know the session

Comment: Now you're just lying, you have hibernate in question tags. Also please don't edit my  question with invalid code.

Comment: i will add 2 photo to question, have a look, there is an example how usually are done,, and please have a look what i have , so you can be more clear